# Dynamic Payload for Each Iteration in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a set of requests for each iteration and I want to change payload of these requests for each iteration.

I can set them in a **BeanShell Preprocessor** like:

```
vars.put("_salesOrderLinesForDispatch", salesOrderLinesForDispatch.toString());
vars.put("_salesOrderLinesForAcknowledgement", salesOrderLinesForAcknowledgement.toString());
vars.put("_salesOrderLinesForCancellation", salesOrderLinesForCancellation.toString());
```

But by this way, payload changes for each request in iteration, not for each iteration.

**vars.put()** inserts these payload into *User Defined Variables*, I want to insert them into *User Parameters*. How can I insert them into *User Parameters* or is there any other way of changing payload for each iteration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute once, so you can add `BeanShell Preprocessor` as child of first request or change  `BeanShell Preprocessor` to `BeanShell Sampler`, that way code will execute once

One of JMeter [best practices] is using JSR223 instead of Beanshell when you can

> Since JMeter 3.1, we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements